# Inventory architecture in WCF / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wcf, architecture

I am working with Datatables, I have no idea how I should do the architecture, for 1 DB and multiple locations of unknown quantity, may increase or decrease in time.

My idea is to make a function on a datatable who would be the "default" of all inventory datatable, so when a admin or user decides to create a new location this function creates the table in the DB, this table will contain the items that the user will insert.

But my problem is, this is possible? because imagine that there are 10 locations, 1 table for each one, who to identify them? and query them so the data is returning to the user?

Comment: When dealing with WCF services, you should try to *avoid* `DataTable` and `DataSet` (because of their quite significant overhead), and instead use proper objects and `List<T>` for collections of objects.

Comment: When you say "locations", do you mean physical locations, like cities or countries? Or locations within a single physical site, like shelves in a store?

Comment: physical locations, friend.